# Diferença de usar ou não o termo function

Tags: javascript, vue.js, sintaxe

Estou iniciando o estudo com o [Vue.js](https://vuejs.org) e me deparei com uma situação dentro de uma das opções e imagino que sirva para outras opções que é o uso do termo function, por exemplo:

```
var vm = new Vue({
  methods : {

    /* assim */

    enviar() {
      // code
    },

    /* ou assim */

    enviar: function() {
      // code
    },

  }
})
```

E com isso minha dúvida é se tem diferença em cada uma das sintaxes e de navegadores?

Comment: Estou trabalhando com `Vue` a mais de um ano, e nunca me fiz essa pergunta, sempre uso `enviar()`, mas se eu nao me engano, você usar `enviar: function(){}` tem alguns problemas com o `this`.

Comment: Então, na documentação eu sempre vi usando a forma com o funcion(){} e dai olhando uns videos vi que foi usando sem, e dai com isso que me surgiu a dúvida.

Comment: Eu acredito que não tenho muita diferença, que é algo como `Arrow Functions`, pois, se fizer um teste, e tentar usar o this, vai dar um erro, voce terá que usar `let self = this`, diferente se usar so com `()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Segundo a documentação na `Mozilla`, `enviar` apesar de ser à forma contraída de `enviar: function()`, a forma contraída é uma função nomeada, enquanto que a segunda é uma função anonima.

> Note : The shorthand syntax uses named function instead of anonymous
>   functions (as in `…foo: function() {}…`). Named functions can be called
>   from the function body (this is impossible for anonymous function as
>   there is no identifier to refer to). For more details, see [function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function#Examples).

**Fonte: [Method definitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Method_definitions#Description)**

Porem se você executar o código abaixo, verá que a forma contraída se comporta como uma função anonima, pelo menos é este comportamento que estou tendo ao executar no Opera.

```js
var teste = {
  nomeada: function nomeada(imprimir) {
    return !imprimir ? nomeada(true) : console.log("nomeada");
  },
  curta(imprimir) {
    return !imprimir ? curta(true) : console.log("curta");
  },
  anomina: function(imprimir) {
    return !imprimir ? anomina(true) : console.log("anomina");
  }
}

try {
  teste.nomeada();
} catch (e) {
  console.error(e.message);
}
try {
  teste.curta();
} catch (e) {
  console.error(e.message);
}
try {
  teste.anomina();
} catch (e) {
  console.error(e.message);
}
```

Um outro ponto curioso, é que na documentação na Mozilla fala que a forma contraída não pode ser utilizada como.

> **Method definitions are not constructable**
>
> All method definitions are not constructors and will throw a TypeError
>   if you try to instantiate them.

**Fonte: [Method definitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Method_definitions#Method_definitions_are_not_constructable)**

Mas ao executar o código abaixo, obtive um comportamento diferente do apontado. Pelo menos foi o que aconteceu ao executar no Opera.

```js
var teste = {
  nomeada: function nomeada() {
    this.nome = "nomeada";
  },
  curta() {
    this.nome = "curta";
  },
  anomina: function() {
    this.nome = "anomina";
  }
}

try {
  console.log(new teste.nomeada);
} catch (e) {
  console.error(e.message);
}
try {
  console.log(new teste.curta);
} catch (e) {
  console.error(e.message);
}
try {
  console.log(new teste.anomina);
} catch (e) {
  console.error(e.message);
}
```

Um outro ponto, é quanto a compatibilidade com os browsers, funções curtas podem ser utilizadas apenas em browsers mais recentes/atualizados. Porém, como está a utilizar o VueJS, deve está utilizando o `vue-cli`, o `gulp-babel` ou qual quer solução que transpile o seu javaScript `ES5` para algo compatível com browser antigos, então isto não chega a ser um problema.

Comment: Então Tobias, muito obrigado pela resposta, mas ainda fiquei com dúvida de qual a melhor forma de usar, se a curta ou a anonima, e ainda não estou usando o vue-cli ou qualquer outra solução que transpile o js, só o vue puro mesmo

Comment: @MarceloDiniz eu te aconselho fortemente a utilizar pelo menos o `gulp-babel`. Mas se decidir continuar sem, e você não tem controle sobre qual browser os usuários vão utilizar, então deve evitar a forma contraída. no mais, não tem um melhor ou pior, a diferença aqui é apenas de estilo, use o que achar mais legivel.